# Databinding not working on Datalist DataSource using sql select statement

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Hi I'm having issues with my Website. I have a button which on it's onclick function i have a SQL function that selects certain data from a table in my database.

The information i get from the database is what i want my DataList source to be. But when i do a Databind, nothing happens, the page is blank.

I don't know if the problem is with my SQL Select Statement, I have put breakpoints just about everywhere but no joy.

This is my code below:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Visible ="false">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="YearLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Year") %>' />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="GenreLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Genre") %>' />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="StarringLabel" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("Starring") %>' />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="RuntimeLabel" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("Runtime") %>' />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="DirectorLabel" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("Director") %>' />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="ProductionLabel" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("Production") %>' />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="CountryLabel" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>' />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="LanguageLabel" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("Language") %>' />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="PlotLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Plot") %>' />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="ReviewLabel" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("Review") %>' />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="RatingLabel" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("Rating") %>' />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="ItemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Item") %>' />
<br />
<br />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:
MetaCriticReviewConnectionString1 %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [Title], [Year], [Genre], [Starring], 
[Runtime],  [Director], [Production], [Country], 
[Language], [Plot],[Review], [Rating], [Item] FROM [Movie]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
databaseCode db = new databaseCode();
string lookupTitle;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Homelink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void readmoreAvengers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lookupTitle = "SELECT * FROM Movie WHERE [Item] ='" + 5 + "'";
    SqlDataReader usersData = db.SQLDataReaderLookup(lookupTitle);

    DataList1.DataSource = usersData;
    DataList1.DataBind();
    DataList1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Movie WHERE [Item] ='" + 5 + "'` => try this query on SQL to see what the result? What is your database look like?

Comment: Hi there, after much struggle ad a bit of research i found out that the problem was with my SQL statement not reading through my external SQL Functions Class.